# Save textual data to file in matlab

Tags: matlab, file, libsvm

I want to save this data in file using matlab

```
optimization finished, #iter = 66
nu = 0.002000
obj = -9.970456, rho = -1.006040
nSV = 60, nBSV = 5
Total nSV = 60

model = 

Parameters: [5x1 double]
  nr_class: 2
   totalSV: 60
       rho: -1.0060
     Label: [2x1 double]
sv_indices: [60x1 double]
     ProbA: []
     ProbB: []
       nSV: [2x1 double]
   sv_coef: [60x1 double]
       SVs: [60x500 double]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save the structure, model, using this command:

```
save myfile model
```

This will save the "model" variable to a file called myfile.mat, you can load it using the "load" command.